# Magento 2 Discount Label and Amount are not showing on checkout cart summary?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have created 10%off cart rule and then applied it.

It's applying correctly but Discount Label and Amount are not showing in checkout cart.

[image]

** UPDATE **

When I'm changing my theme to default luma then

Discount is showing.(Below Image)

[image]

What to do to show that row?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> /vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/**checkout_cart_index.xml**

Take below code from above file

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
   </item>
</item>
```

Insert it in **`checkout_cart_index.xml`** file of **Magento_checkout** in **your theme** by **Overriding** it there.

Now you can see discount there.

Comment: what will be the location of this file with name `checkout_cart_index.xml`

Comment: I am asking about the location of that place where i need to put this code, that is where in my theme?

Comment: Do we need to override the same file from where we copied this code or somewhere else? Because it is not working with the same file

Comment: I have created a file at location `magento_root\app\design\frontend\Theme_package\theme\Magento_SalesRule\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml` but it is not working with it

Comment: @Miroslav Due to your edit, solution is not understandable.

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI Insert it in overrided checkout_cart_index.xml file of module-checkout in your theme like ithat way it is called in Magento‌​_SalesRule module.

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI found solution?

Comment: I found I needed to add it to `checkout_index_index.xml` for this to work. `checkout_cart_index.xml` refers to the cart page, not checkout page, which is where i was having this issue...... In `<item name="sidebar">`, there's a further item called "block-totals". Within the children of that (there should be subtotal, shipping and grand-total), you can add the above code. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!

Comment: yes, I have tried and copied Magento_SalesRules folder to my custom theme. Still not working ? Has anyone find solution. Its perfectly working with luma theme.

Comment: @Nitesh In my case, both coupon label and coupon codes are displayed in brackets. Is there any way to only display coupon label in cart and checkout page?

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya No idea for that

Answer (score 1):

Complete code of app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml file

```
                  <container name="checkout.cart.totals.container" as="totals" label="Shopping Cart Totals">
                        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/totals.phtml">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals</item>
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals</item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/subtotal</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>


                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>

                                                <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Estimated Total</item>
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </container>
```