# How to display discount amount on shopping cart page magento 2 custom theme?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, discount, custom-theme

> Actually i want to display discount amount once we apply the discount
>   code in shopping cart page magento2 in custom theme.Please guide me if
>   anyone have any idea.

Comment: Where you want to display discount amount on cart page?

Comment: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165139/magento-2-discount-label-and-amount-are-not-showing-on-checkout-cart-summary](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165139/magento-2-discount-label-and-amount-are-not-showing-on-checkout-cart-summary)