# Change label for Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent

Tell me how can I remove the word "Discount" and parentheses from the label

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165139/magento-2-discount-label-and-amount-are-not-showing-on-checkout-cart-summary

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-change-the-text-quot-discount-quot-to-another-custom-text/td-p/123591

Comment: I created this thread after trying these solutions. They do not work

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in your theme "i18n" and add en_US.csv , with the help of en_US.csv you can change "Discount" string to another string, it's one of the easiest method.

Comment: This is proper way than overiding the file

Comment: It doesn`t work for me(

Comment: It`s work but need to change "Discount (%1)"

Answer (score 0):

Override this file in your theme or module:

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/summary/discount.html

And paste this content.
You might need to add some css to make it visible.

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals discount">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
     <!-- add css display: block; if your theme extends from luma -->
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponCode()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': name}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: This method remove all title
I need to remove only "Discount " word

Comment: See the class span tag having class "discount coupon". This is set to display:none; You to need add css to make it display: block; You will get the desired result.